# Java docx4j modify template for header footer with SQL data

Tags: java, jaxb, footer, docx4j

What I am wanting to do is take in a word doc/docx template which already has pre-designed headers and footers and replace certain words with words applicable with that document generated from what a user has input and has been saved through MySQL. I already have a program that works to get the user input and saves to the MySQL. However, I'm a little confused at how the word manipulation would work into this. 
I found docx4j and a tutorial that shows what I am looking for [here](http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-complex-word-docx-documents-programatically-docx4j) and have found on another question on this site example code [here](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/BindingHandler.java). As I'm a beginner in using this, the things I'm confused on are:

- I understand JAXB is used for converting to and from XML. Why is this relevant in a situation like this? Or if it's not, in what case would it be?
- I am seeing two versions of loading:

  ```
  WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File("P:\\Engineering\\Projects\\Naming\\EX_TEMP.docx"));
  ```

........ and the second example:

```
    private WordprocessingMLPackage getTemplate(String name) throws Docx4JException, FileNotFoundException {
    WordprocessingMLPackage template = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream(new File(name)));
    return template;
}
```

(where would you put the file directory on the second code, or how can you specify the file you want to load?)

- what does hyperlinkresolver do and why is it necessary? (second link)
- what is applying binding in this situation? (second link)
- what is the content accessor? (first link)
- am I going about this the right way, or is there an easier/better way of doing this?

I am using Eclipse with Java on a Windows 7 if that helps.
I would appreciate any help, thanks!
Also if anyone has any examples with good comments or explanations, that would be helpful!

Comment: I'm only allowed to use two links above, but I wanted to include [this link](http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/plutext-docx4j_on_a_page-v300.pdf) as a useful breakdown that makes some things a little simpler to understand, but doesn't really answer most of my questions. I just figured it could be useful if someone else is struggling to understand this stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably ought to take a step back and decide which approach to injecting your data you want to take.  Docx4j supports three approaches:

1. replacing variables on the document surface (brittle but simple)
2. mail merge (using MERGEFIELD), good for legacy documents
3. content control data binding (your 2nd link; the modern/sophisticated/powerful approach, but you need to understand XML, and may be overkill here)

For answers to most of your specific questions, please take the time to read docx4j's [Getting Started](http://www.docx4java.org) guide.

Comment: Thank you Jason your beginners guide was helpful. I will be attempting to go with the first method of just replacing variables on the document surface provided I can get to the header and footer. One thing I am still stuck on is the JAXBElement. I understand that this is part of the zip that makes up the word doc, but I'm not understanding where it is defined. Every example I have tried to implement lacks an origin from what I could tell. Perhaps I was missing something. I read you need to use the get/setContents, but how? Thanks again!

Comment: JAXB has javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement which is used to wrap some objects to provide extra info about the corresponding Xml Element.  In docx4j, each "Part" which has contents represented using JAXB has a field containing the root object for its content model which you can access via the getContents().  Unfortunately, we called that field jaxbElement, which might be a bit confusing.

Comment: getContents() gets you whatever object is tied to the part in question.  So for the Main Document Part, its a org.docx4j.wml.Document object; for a header or footer it is something else.  You then manipulate the Document object using its methods.